# Simplify the variational bound

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm trying to understand the following proof from [Deep Unsupervised Learning Using Nonequilibrium Thermodynamics](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.03585.pdf).

This particular version of the proof is found in: [Denoising Diffusion Probabilistic Models](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.11239).

[image: Proof]

I'm confused by the move from (19) to (20) and the move from (20) to (21) though.

For (19) to (20) I tried applying Bayes Rule to $q(x_{t-1}|x_t,x_0)$ but that didn't help.

I also see:

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}{q(x_t|x_{t-1})}\\
&= \frac{p_\theta(x_{t-1}|x_t)}{q(x_t|x_{t-1})} 
\cdot \frac{q(x_t|x_{t-1}) \cdot q(x_{t-1}|x_0)}{q(x_t|x_0)}\\
\end{align*}
$$

but I can't simplify any further to (20).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not going to help you much but.

from 19 to 20.

Like the first paper said, $q(x_t|x_{t-1})$ is Markov process, it can be  $q(x_t|x_{t-1}, x_0)$

Then Bayes Rule comes, becomes (20), then you can substitute 2 to T in t in mid term, then there is some elimination, you can derive (21).

I still don't get $D_{KL}$ part (22). I am trying to figure this out.

Comment: This might go better on a comment.